# Amazon S3 domain hosting: CNAME too long

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, dns, cname

So I have a bucket set up on Amazon S3, which is configured as a site, and is accessible via the endpoint address.

When I go to paste this endpoint address into 1and1's control panel, it tells me it's too long (past the ridiculous 30 character limit).

What are my options instead, here? 1and1 allows me to change the DNS, or add an IP address as the A record. If either is applicable here, what value would it be set to, bearing in mind my bucket is in the Ireland datacenter.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here was my solution after 1&1 were ridiculously unhelpful. It involves an external DNS provider, but oh well, it works just fine.

I signed up for Namecheap's FreeDNS service with the naked domain (i.e. don't include the 'www'). Point your DNS records with 1&1 to use Namecheap's servers.

The records are then set up as:

```
@  http://www.yourdomain.com  URL redirect (301)  3600
www  your.long.cname.aws.amazon.com.  CNAME (Alias)  3600
```

The top line sorts out the naked domain issue (and I seem to recall trying it set to the CNAME also and it didn't work), and the TTLs can be changed for whatever you feel is appropriate.

Comment: +1 for following up with your solution to this utterly annoying issue, thanks! Please note that AWS offers a DNS service themselves (see [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/)), which would allow you to keep everything centralized, plus quite some AWS specific benefits for advanced use cases (e.g. the recently announced [Multi-Region Latency Based Routing](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws.html)); it has a rather small, but eventually still relevant [price tag](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/) attached though.

Comment: With the above setting, your S3 bucket should be named **www.yourdomain.com**, seemingly you don't need another bucket called **yourdomain.com**. When I setup my S3 buckets as recommended by Amazon, i.e, **yourdomain.com** is the main bucket and **www.yourdomain.com** is another bucket setup to redirect to former one; I ended up with a re-direct loop. Here's a thread from the [namecheap forum.](https://community.namecheap.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7694)

Answer (score 3):

I rang the 1and1 technical helpline with the same problem. The answer: if the cname alias is more than 32 characters, then ring your host and ask them for a shorter cname alias. Yes, 1and1 genuinely think that you should ring Amazon Web Services and ask them to reconfigure their load-balancing software for you!

I immediately cancelled my domain name registration with 1and1. That or a domain name transfer to another provider are the only options if you want to go with Amazon S3.

Comment: Because that's not idiotic of them to suggest at all, right? Geez. Dealing with amateurs there.

Comment: same thing happened with me. Finally got something working. I'm using sites.google and my cname is too long. I was able to verify my site by adding a subdomain.  But all I can do is http redirect. Which isn't what I want.  The iFrame doesn't work. This is 2.5 years later. I'd recommend not using 1&1.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you're somehow getting a static IP assigned to your S3 *bucket*, I'm afraid there's not much you can do.

You could always try using using 1&1's [HTTP redirection service](http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_admin/domain_dest/4.html), but I'm not sure what the downsides will be for your domain (in terms of what URL shows up in Google searches, etc).